# In practice, do large prime generators account for difference in gaps between primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

It is my understanding that a method for creating large primes is to:

- pick a random large number,
- check the number against trial division of a set of smaller prime numbers,
- check with something like Miller-Rabin
- if not prime increment by 2 and repeat

Is this method used in practice? And if so, does it matter that the method is biased towards primes that follow large gaps? How would you alter the method to make it more fair?

Comment: Have you read the [Million-Key Question paper](https://www.usenix.org/node/197198) all about identifying and distinguishing the various prime generation methods that are used in practice?  If not, you should—it is an excellent paper with beautiful visualizations.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage, thanks, the paper basically answered my question, as well as the duplicate link.